# Как убедиться, что Cache-control работает?

Tags: оптимизация, кэширование

Я включил заголовок Cache-control в Nginx'e:

```
expires max;
```

Но как теперь точно проверить, что он работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать через Curl:

```
curl -I ruhighload.com
```

Увидим:

```
...
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
...
```

Либо можно использовать это [Online инструмент](http://highloadtools.com/cachecontrol), он покажет правильно ли используется Cache-control и будет ли кешироваться ответ.

P.S. Правильно включать Cache-control тоже нужно уметь, [например в PHP](http://ruhighload.com/post/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+Cache-control+%D0%B2+PHP).